# Node.JS Stops working and console gets flooded with dots

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loops, foreach

ScreenShot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2UvF.png

I'm trying to make a code to return two arrays, but when the function calls the final part of code, the console gets flooded with dots (screenshot) and stop working, like a crash.

I'm using MongoJS driver for database connection.

Here's the part of my code:

```
lastcollect.find({from_id: usuario}, {limit: 10, sort: {time: -1}}, function(err, echoData) {
    if (err || !echoData) {
        console.log("No messages found");
    } else {
        var users = [];
        var n = 0;
        var max = echoData.length;
        echoData.forEach(function(returnData) {
            usercollect.findOne({idu: returnData.to_id}, {}, function(err, echoData) {
                if (err || !echoData) {
                    console.log("Req.Info error", err);
                    n = n + 1;
                } else {
                    n = n + 1;
                    var r = [];
                    r['name'] = echoData.name;
                    r['avatar'] = echoData.avatar;
                    r['phone'] = echoData.phone;
                    r['idu'] = echoData.idu;
                    users[echoData.idu] = r;
                    console.log('DB exec ' + n);
                    if (n === max) {
                        console.log('DB exec END');
                        var data = [];
                        data.data = echoData;
                        data.users = users;
                        console.log('users', users);
                        console.log('data', data);
                        io.sockets.emit('return lastusers ' + usuario, data);
                    }
                }
            });
    });

    }
});
```

I'm stuck at this for 4 hours, so if anyone can help i would appreciate.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you include your screenshot, please?

Comment: I`ve uploaded to imgur: http://i.imgur.com/Shyihhb.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your line

```
users[echoData.idu] = r;
```

You are setting the value at index echoData.idu to r. The problem is your array begins un-initialized, and I'm guessing echoData.idu is not a simple count. The ","s you are seeing are the empty spots in the array! Try this to see what I mean:

```
var testArray = [];
testArray[9] = "a";
console.log(testArray);
```

I would recommend saying instead

```
users.push(r);
```

or

```
users[n] = r; //because n is your counter.
```

If you don't care about the order, you could also speed up this call by using the excellent async npm libary, here: https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: Thanks! I was already nervous and i haven't see this, because console on node dont displays the error sometimes.